# Как остановить FSM в aiogram3.0.0b7?

Tags: python, state, aiogram-3.x

Я изучаю aiogram 3 b7 и столкнулся с проблемой, что не знаю как остановить состояние FSM. я видел решение использовать `await state.finish()`, но на 3 aiogram оно не работает. как мне сделать это? Код:

```
cansel = Router()

@cansel.message(Text(text=["❌ отмена"], ignore_case=True))
async def cmd_cansel(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
```

Comment: а что за переменная `cansel`?

Comment: не должно ли быть там `dp`?

Comment: cansel - роутер. я забыл добавить эту переменную в код

Comment: так добавьте, нажмите кнопку [edit]

Comment: добавил этот участок кода

Answer (score 1):

```
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram import F, Router

router : Router = Router() # твой роутер

@router.message(Command("cancel"))  # Сработает при команде /cancel
@router.message(F.text.casefold() == "cancel") # И если в сообщение есть "cancel"
async def cancel_handler(message: Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    current_state = await state.get_state()  # Получаем текущий state
    if current_state is None:  # Если его нет, то ничего не возвращаем
        return    
    '''А вот иначе, завершаем state и прописываем в лог'''
    lg.info("Cancelling state %r", current_state)
    await state.clear()
    await message.answer("Вы отменили действие")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение, но не уверен лучшее ли оно. Решение:

```
await state.set_state(None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await state.clear()
```

убирает текущее состояние (стоит заметить что update_data которая там храниться, если вы ее добавили пропадет)